# DTEXEC doesn't trigger dtsx package in a power shell when triggered from java but works from command prompt on local machine

Tags: java, powershell, ssis, dtexec

I'm calling a `dtsx` file in `PowerShell(test.ps1)` using below:

```
& $dtexec /f "$dtsx"
```

This works fine when I run the `test.ps1` from command prompt in local machine but the same doesn't even trigger when `test.ps1` is triggered from a java application.
please help.

Comment: Please share any error messages or debug information you have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check if any other Powershell runs for You when started from Java, and only this particular one fails. 
At some point I had similar problem. It turned out, that I was using Powershell module that required to 64bit powershell instance while I was running 32bit java process. This in turn was spawning 32bit Powershell process (You can check that with `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`) that could not run what I was asking it to run.